# how to get instant updated listview which data is providing from database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I send data to database from one device and refresh listview by other device, but I can't see the updated item on listview which I recently inserted to database, how can I get instant updated listview? please someone help me to solve this problem. here is my code

GroupWallActivity.java

```
public class GroupWallActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private static final String TAG = GroupWallActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ImageView groupProPic;
private TextView groupName;
private TextView varsity;
private Button postButton;
private Button memberButton;
private Button fileButton;
private EditText postText;
private ListView postListView;

private String userIdString;
private String groupIdString;
private String groupNameString;
private String universityNameString;
private String postTextString;

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

private ArrayList<PostModel> postList;
private CustomAdapterPost customAdapterPost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_wall);

    groupName= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.groupNameTV);
    varsity= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.varsityTV);
    postButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.postBtn);
    memberButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.groupMemberButton);
    fileButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.groupFileButton);
    postText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postTextET);
    postListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.postListLV);
    swipeRefreshLayout= (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    userIdString=getIntent().getStringExtra("UserId");
    groupIdString=getIntent().getStringExtra("GroupId");
    groupNameString=getIntent().getStringExtra("GroupName");
    universityNameString=getIntent().getStringExtra("UniversityName");

    groupName.setText(groupNameString);
    varsity.setText(universityNameString);

    postList=db.getPostFromPostTable(groupIdString);
    if(postList.size()!=0 && postList.size()>0) {

        customAdapterPost = new CustomAdapterPost(getApplicationContext(), 0, postList);
        postListView.setAdapter(customAdapterPost);
    }
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            postShow(userIdString,groupIdString);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRefresh()
{
    customAdapterPost.notifyDataSetChanged();
    postShow(userIdString,groupIdString);
}

public void insertPost(View view) {
    postTextString=postText.getText().toString().trim();
    postAnnouncement(userIdString, groupIdString, postTextString);
}

public void goToMemberActivity(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(GroupWallActivity.this, MemberActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("UserId",userIdString);
    intent.putExtra("GroupId",groupIdString);
    intent.putExtra("GroupName",groupNameString);
    intent.putExtra("UniversityName",universityNameString);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void postAnnouncement(final String userId,final String groupId,final String postBody) {

    String tag_string_req = "req_register";
    progressDialog.setMessage("Posting ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_POST, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    // Now store the user in sqlite

                    SQLiteHandler postDelete=new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    postDelete.deletePost();

                    JSONArray groupArray = jObj.optJSONArray("post");

                    for(int i=0; i < groupArray.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject post = groupArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String postUniqueId = post.getString("post_unique_id");
                        String userUniqueId = post.getString("user_unique_id");
                        String groupUniqueId= post.getString("group_unique_id");
                        String userName = post.getString("user_name");
                        String postBody = post.getString("post_body");
                        String createdAt = post.getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in  table
                        db.addPostToPostTable(postUniqueId, userUniqueId, groupUniqueId, userName, postBody, createdAt);

                    }

                    // Launch GroupWall activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GroupWallActivity.this, GroupWallActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("UserId",userIdString);
                    intent.putExtra("GroupId",groupIdString);
                    intent.putExtra("GroupName",groupNameString);
                    intent.putExtra("UniversityName",universityNameString);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                } else {

                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("user_unique_id", userId);
            params.put("group_unique_id", groupId);
            params.put("post_body", postBody);

            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(strReq);
}

private void postShow(final String userId,final String groupId) {

    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_POST, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    // Now store the user in sqlite

                    SQLiteHandler dbDelete = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    dbDelete.deletePost();

                    JSONArray groupArray = jObj.optJSONArray("post");

                    for(int i=0; i < groupArray.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject post = groupArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String postUniqueId = post.getString("post_unique_id");
                        String userUniqueId = post.getString("user_unique_id");
                        String groupUniqueId = post.getString("group_unique_id");
                        String userName = post.getString("user_name");
                        String postBody = post.getString("post_body");
                        String createdAt = post.getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in  table
                        db.addPostToPostTable(postUniqueId, userUniqueId, groupUniqueId, userName, postBody, createdAt);
                    }

                    customAdapterPost.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hideDialog();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("user_unique_id", userId);
            params.put("group_unique_id", groupId);

            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(strReq);
}

private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);

    db.deleteUsers();

    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(GroupWallActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.appbar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.logout) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

CustomAdapterPost.java

```
public class CustomAdapterPost extends ArrayAdapter<PostModel> {
TextView userName;
TextView postText;

public CustomAdapterPost(Context context, int resource, List<PostModel> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    PostModel postModel=getItem(position);
    if (convertView==null){
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_post_view,parent,false);
    }
    userName= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postUserNameTV);
    postText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postTextTV);

    userName.setText(postModel.getUserName());
    postText.setText(postModel.getPostBody());
    return  convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: In your postShow method, you updated the database. But you have not updated your ArrayList, postList=db.getPostFromPostTable(groupIdString);
, before "customAdapterPost.notifyDataSetChanged();".

Answer (score 0):

You did not send the data to the other device, Android `SQLIteDatabase` is local and is for only the device that created it. If you want it to appear on another device, considering getting an online database, or practice using `Socket`.

Comment: May be you don't see my code.Any way, first of all I send the data to server then if the response is positive i store the data to sqlite database and then show it to listview using adapter class but my problem is listview don't show that data which i post recently, I hope you understand my  problem, please help me to solve it.